# KnockoutJS - How to refresh attribute values?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this code

```
<input type="text" data-bind="attr: { 'value': name }"/>
```

I did not use `value: name` because I want the data to be saved into model only after clicking a "save" button

I have this function in viewModel that triggers when I click a "reset" button. The purpose of the "reset" button is to revert all values of a form to the one in the data model.

```
function FooViewModel()
{
    ...
    self.cancelFooUpdate = function(data, event)
    {
        data.name.valueHasMutated();
        ...
    };
}
```

However, this does not seem to be working. Is it because I am using `attr`?

Comment: You might be interested in [this blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html)

Comment: Thanks for post dan but I already have solution for that editable problem. I specifically want to know why `attr` doesn't updated even if the value is changed.